# Rails: Virtual Association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Invoice model that has an status_id attribute, this model belongs to Status models.

The Invoice.status_id can be "0 => active" or "2 => closed" in the DB.

The thing is in my Status model i also have ":id => 1, :name => due", but this is only when the Invoice.payment_date is less than today.

So my question is how can i something like

```
i = Invoice.find(:first)
i.status.name # i need this to return due if the Invoice.status_id == 0 and
              # Invoice.payment_date < Date.today
```

Obviously the above code is always returning the name based on the value Invoice.status_id, because the association is correct.

I hope it make sense and somebody can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the above code returning for you? And you say, *Obviously the above code is always returning the name based on the value Invoice.status_id, because the association is correct.* -- so what is the problem?

Comment: is not a problem, is that i dont know how to override this behavior. I need a way for the Status model knows the result of Invoice.status_id, and when this method (Invoice#status_id, yes i overrided the attribute with a method) returns 5, the Status with id 5 gets returned. Today the Status returned is based on the status_id db value.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason Status has to be a model? If not, I would make it a method like this:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  def status
    if closed?
      "closed"
    elsif payment_date < Date.today
      "due"
    else
      "active"
    end
  end
end
```

Then add a boolean field `closed` to the invoices table.

Comment: But it changes from active to due automatically when the date passes. He doesn't want to have to update the field on that day.

Comment: I thinks it has to be a model, because also i must be able to filter the invoice by status

Comment: It doesn't have to be a model in order to filter by status. Just use conditions in your find statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking the problem the wrong way.
Once i read a little more of ActiveRecord and searchlogic, it came to me: named scope!!!